# How to concatenate RDD[String] with Array[String] to produce String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I convert `RDD[String]` and `Array[String]` to String?

I am getting the below error,

```
<console>:34: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
required: String
```

The idea is to get the distinct date from a column in SchemaRDD and concat the date with a constant String as `/home/tmp/date=`. So I should concat both and output should be

```
val path =  /home/tmp/date=20140901,/home/tmp/date=20140902,/home/tmp/date=20140903,/home/tmp/date=20140904,... so on
```

path will be keyed in `sc.textFiles(path)` to read the entire dataset.

At this step, while reading the data I get the conversion error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hare's one approach. First, set up the example:

```
val prefix = "/home/tmp/date="
val dates =  Array("20140901", "20140902", "20140903", "20140904")
val datesRDD = sc.parallelize(dates, 2)
```

Zipping the the prefix in is easy:

```
val datesWithPrefixRDD = datesRDD.map(s => prefix + s)
datesWithPrefixRDD.foreach(println)
```

This produces:

```
/home/tmp/date=20140901
/home/tmp/date=20140903
/home/tmp/date=20140902
/home/tmp/date=20140904
```

But you asked for a single string. The obvious first attempt has some comma problems:

```
val bad = datesWithPrefixRDD.fold("")((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2)
println(bad)
```

This produces:

```
, , /home/tmp/date=20140901, /home/tmp/date=20140902, , /home/tmp/date=20140903, /home/tmp/date=20140904
```

The problem is the way Spark RDD's fold() method starts the concatenation with the empty string I provided, once for the whole RDD and once for each partition. But we can deal with empty strings:

```
val good = datesWithPrefixRDD.fold("")((s1, s2) =>
  s1 match {
    case "" => s2
    case s => s + ", " + s2
  })
println(good)
```

Then we get:

```
/home/tmp/date=20140901, /home/tmp/date=20140902, /home/tmp/date=20140903, /home/tmp/date=20140904
```

**EDIT:** Actually, reduce() produces a tidier answer because it solves the "extra comma" problems:

```
val alternative = datesWithPrefixRDD.reduce((s1, s2) => s1 + ", " + s2)
println(alternative)
```

Again we get:

```
/home/tmp/date=20140901, /home/tmp/date=20140902, /home/tmp/date=20140903, /home/tmp/date=20140904
```